# Not able to use static image after getting the value of dictionary key and using it in HTML template. Unable to use value in HTML

Tags: django, dictionary

I have loaded the static

```html
<div class="row">
     <img src="{% static 'wea_app/icons/{{ mainresult.icons }}.png' %}">
<div>
```

If I print the 'icons', I get the value in terminal. The value name also matches the name of the static file. How can I pass it to the static path which contains the image of my weather. I just want the value to pass to path so I can get the image according to the weather from my static folder.

myviews.py file

```
mainresult = {
        "city":city,
        "temprature": a['current']['temp'],
        "description": a['current']['weather'][0]['description'],
        "icons": a['current']['weather'][0]['icon'],
        "feels": a['current']['feels_like'],
        "windspeed" :  a['current']['wind_speed'],
        "timezone" : a['timezone'],
        "pressure" : a['current']['pressure'],
        "humidity" : a['current']['humidity'],
        "dt" : a['current']['dt'],
    }
    

    context = {"mainresult":mainresult}

    return render(request,'wea_app/index.html',context)
```

Comment: According to my limited knowledge, you can't inject template variables to static template tag like you have done `{% static 'wea_app/icons/{{ mainresult.icons }}.png' %}`. You can either use javascript and change the URL(not a good solution) or send the static file URL with the context. CAn you provide the models???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<img src="{% static 'wea_app/icons/'|add:mainresult.icons|add:'.png' %}"> 
<div>
```

You should be able to concatenate strings with the add

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the value of the key icons in the views.py file:

```
...

mainresult = {
        "city":city,
        "temprature": a['current']['temp'],
        "description": a['current']['weather'][0]['description'],
        "icons": a['current']['weather'][0]['icon'],
        "feels": a['current']['feels_like'],
        "windspeed" :  a['current']['wind_speed'],
        "timezone" : a['timezone'],
        "pressure" : a['current']['pressure'],
        "humidity" : a['current']['humidity'],
        "dt" : a['current']['dt'],
    }

icon = mainresult['icons']
    
context = {"mainresult": mainresult, "icon": icon}

return render(request, 'wea_app/index.html', context)
...
```

Then the HTML:

```
...

<div class="row">
    <img src="static/wea_app/icons/{{ icon }}.png" />
</div>
...
```

Comment: I am still not able to get the png image file even though printed value of 'icon' in terminal matches the exact name of my image file. @joao_lucas

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, it should work now